# Act upon document upload in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, file-upload, sharepoint-2010

I've been requested to help a friend where he wants all uploaded documents to be converted to PDF and save the URL into a small database for later use.

Can anyone explain me what should I look or what method I need to override to create such workflow?

This needs to be available to all documents (even images).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this post](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/04/using-pdf-converter-from-sharepoint.html), it does exactly what you need although you may need to pull some tricks to write the URL into an external database. Writing it to a SharePoint list is easy.

Ping me if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use third party API like one suggested by Muhimbi. to create your custom one you would have to create a event handler in which you can write code to convert your document or images to PDF. for PDF conversion you can use itextsharp
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Comment: I work with iText# for sometime now, it does a poor job converting word documents, the best convertions need Office Client installed in a server where we the conversion takes place.